# Laravel can't create migration table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `topsis`.`migrations` (errno: 126 "Index is corrupted") (Connection:
> mysql, SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null
> auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch`
> int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate
> 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

I am trying to migrate the default table in Laravel and this error gets shown.

Comment: `: 126 "Index is corrupted` <<<=== that's the actual error. Can you drop the database and re-create it? Is this on a production server or your local system?

Comment: its on my local system. I already drop the database and creating new database